# Convergence of series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln^\beta(n)}{n^\alpha}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I know if $\beta = 0$ it converges $\iff$ $\alpha > 1$. Also, it doesn't converge if $\alpha = 0$. I don't know what test to apply for the rest of cases. Any hints?

Comment: You can use the [integral test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence) to find the answer, which is explained [here](http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/series/bertrand/bertrand.html)

Comment: Or the Cauchy Condensation Test.

Comment: For integer $\beta$, this is the $\beta^{th}$ derivative of the $\zeta$ function.

Comment: In fact, the name is Bertrand series. http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/series/bertrand/bertrand.html

Comment: I don't this should be marked as a duplicate, because this question includes the case (in the other question) where $\beta < 0$, whereas that question strictly assumes that $\beta \ge 0$.

Answer (score 1):

For $\epsilon>0$ we have $1<\ln(n) <n^\epsilon $ for almost all $n$, therefore (replacing $\epsilon$ with $\frac{\epsilon}{|\beta|}$ if $\beta\ne 0$)
$$n^{-\epsilon} < \ln^\beta(n)<n^\epsilon $$
for almost all $n$. Thus for $\beta>0$ and $\alpha>1$ we have convergence (pick $\epsilon<\alpha-1$) and for $\beta<0$ and $\alpha<1$ we have divergence.